# @FullUrl - Undocumented function

Tags: xpages

While going through sample database for Extension Library I found a function `@FullUrl`. I wasn't able to find this in the help documentation but it works something like this. If I put a statement like `@FullUrl("myXPage.xsp")` then it outputs `/path/mydatabase.nsf/myXPage.xsp`.

Searching the web returned [this link from XPages cheat sheet](http://xpagescheatsheet.com/cheatsheet.nsf/url.xsp) which mentions its usage same as I described above. What is the support of IBM on this function? Is the absence of its documentation from help just a mistake or it is not intended to be used in production applications?

*NOTE: I am using Lotus Notes 8.5.3*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are mor undocumented functions

```
        // Document helpers
    addFunction(FCT_TOPPARENTID, "@TopParentID", "(doc:W):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_TOPPARENTUNID, "@TopParentUNID", "(doc:W):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$

    // URL handling
    addFunction(FCT_FULLURL, "@FullUrl", "(str:T):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_ABSOLUTEURL, "@AbsoluteUrl", "(str:T):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_ENCODEURL, "@EncodeUrl", "(str:T):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_ISABSOLUTEURL, "@IsAbsoluteUrl", "(str:T):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$

    // XPages helpers
    addFunction(FCT_ERRORMESSAGE, "@ErrorMessage", "(str:Tcomp:W):V"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_WARNINGMESSAGE, "@WarningMessage", "(str:Tcomp:W):V"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$
    addFunction(FCT_INFORMATIONMESSAGE, "@InfoMessage", "(str:Tcomp:W):V"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$

    // Domino View
    addFunction(FCT_VIEWICONURL, "@ViewIconUrl", "(icon:I):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ $NON-NLS-2$

    addFunction(FCT_NORMALIZESUBJECT, "@NormalizeSubject", "(subject:T):T", "(subject:T, maxlength:I):T"); // $NON-NLS-1$ // $NON-NLS-2$ // $NON-NLS-3$
```

I've blogged about this a year ago http://www.eknori.de/2011-11-22/extension-library-8-5-3-undocumented-functions/

You can find them in the NotesFunctionsEx.java file in the ExtensionLibraryOpenNTF-853.20121022-1354\srcOpenNTF\eclipse\plugins\com.ibm.xsp.extlib.domino\src\com\ibm\xsp\extlib\javascript dir ( unpack srcOpenNTF.zip first )

You can use the code as a reference on how to build your own SSJS extension ( http://www.openntf.org/Internal/home.nsf/project.xsp?databaseName=CN=NotesOSS2/O=NotesOSS!!Projects\pmt.nsf&documentId=6159D09FC2EA663C862579F30028803E&action=openDocument )

So, if you are unsecure if the functions will not be part of the extLib in future releases, you can include the into your own extension ...

Comment: So it would be better to keep away from `@FullUrl`! Pity I kind of liked this function.

Answer (score 0):

The only reference I can find is in the XPages Extension Library book. So it is possible it is part of extlib.

It is possible the documentation is out of sync. If it isn't however, undocumented features are normally not supported. This could be due to a couple of reasons.

- the feature does not work properly or hasn't been fully tested.
- the feature is liable to be dropped/changed in a later release that will break functionality.
- the feature was designed for internal usage only.

Using such calls in production is at your own risk. It's a long weekend here so I am not in a position to verify the status.